# Pandas groupby and transform with row filter

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with the following multi-indexed dataframe:

[image]

I would like to get the average of column 'EY' for all the rows grouped by ['date','SECTOR'] but only if EST_UNIV == 1.

I could do the following:

[image]

This gets me most of what I need, but you'll notice the # of rows dropped down from 6553 to 1313.

I would like to pull in the values for all the rows in the original dataframe, even if EST_UNIV == 0, but I would like the average calculation to only apply for rows where EST_UNIV == 1.

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Could you please update your question by [adding data frames as text and not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for helper column for missing values if not match condition:

```
df['new'] = (df.assign(new = df['EY'].where(df.EST_UNIV.eq(1)))
               .groupby(['date','SECTOR'])['new']
               .transform('mean'))
```